# Finding missing records from two tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compare total number of records for a particular table in two databases. They are from the same database, but both the database are running in two different servers.

Table structure is same on both the tables , but no of records varies on both the tables.

I want to find out the missing records from both these tables.

```
mysql> select count(*) from dlfilerank;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    38259 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)


mysql> select count(*) from dlfilerank;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    38359 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

So, dump both tables into two files and then see the difference with diff:

```
 mysql -h host1 -NB -e "SELECT * FROM db.table ORDER BY id" > t1
 mysql -h host2 -NB -e "SELECT * FROM db.table ORDER BY id" > t2

 diff -u t1 t2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `id` is a unique field in the tables...  To find what is in db1.tbl but not in db2.tbl:

```
SELECT db1.tbl.*
FROM db1.tbl
LEFT JOIN db2.tbl USING(id)
WHERE db2.tbl.id IS NULL;
```

Swap db names to check the other direction.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'db1' 
AND `TABLE_NAME` NOT IN  (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'db2');
```

Comment: This compares metadata, not data. So it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: As @Colin'tHart points out, this does not answer the question. I wouldn't worry about it too much - I've done the same thing frequently enough - you only have to look at this [morning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/253676/removing-multiple-values-using-if-else-statements/253692#253692)! Just keep trying and welcome to the forum! :-)