# Removing multiple values using if else statements?

Tags: sql-server

I have a program that downloads raw data from a sensor. Due to to some specifications made in the SQL code, there are values that are duplicated which needs to be deleted to maintain data integrity.

Below is a snapshot of the dataset:
[image]

Do note that is is just a snapshot of july 10th. I have 33 other devices all of them have data dates from july 10th all the way through october.

Is there a way for me to traverse the whole dataset and find a way to set conditional statements. For example, if there are 2 values that share the same timing, take the row that has the "1" value.

At the same time, i would like to point out that this dataset is data that is collected 24/7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to produce a windowed record ID for each row, grouped by RoomCode and Time as per this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce97c449831d45829b8975e8678036da).

For each of the semi-duplicate rows (where RoomCode and Time are the same but Occupancy is different) this produces an incrementing number based on occupancy in descending order (so 1 = 1 and 0 = 2).

Place this in a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and then inner join your table to the CTE based on all columns except Occupancy where the ROW_NUMBER() pseudo column is > 1.

Example:

```
;WITH DataCTE AS (
SELECT RoomCode, Occupancy, Time, DayFromDate, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RoomCode, Time ORDER BY Occupancy DESC) AS RN
FROM DataPoints
)

DELETE d1
FROM DataPoints d1
INNER JOIN DataCTE d2
ON d1.RoomCode = d2.RoomCode
 AND d1.Occupancy = d2.Occupancy
 AND d1.Time = d2.Time
 AND d1.DayFromDate = d2.DayFromDate
WHERE d2.RN > 1
```

Result:

```
RoomCode    Occupancy   Time    DayFromDate
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 08:00:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  1   07/10/2019 08:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  1   07/10/2019 09:00:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  1   07/10/2019 09:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  1   07/10/2019 10:00:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  1   07/10/2019 10:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 11:00:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 11:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 12:00:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 12:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 13:00:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 13:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 14:00:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 14:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 15:00:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  1   07/10/2019 15:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  0   07/10/2019 16:00:00     Wednesday
```

You may need to massage this example and include additional columns in the PARTITION BY clause to ensure you're only selecting the correct near-duplicates but this should achieve the result you're after.

P.S. Its always a good idea in questions to include DDL (table definition), DML (INSERT statement with example data) and expected results to help clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR this doesn't answer the question as asked, but rather picks out the two row combinations that are highlighted - which essentially boils down to selecting out islands of 0 - 1 - 0 of `occupancy` and not runs of, say 0 - 1 - 1 - 0 or more.

This was tricky and requires the use of the [LAG() AND LEAD()](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9127/sql-server-window-functions-lead-and-lag/) and the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/) functions. Your requirement is made difficult by virtue of the fact that apparently you do **not** want runs of `occupancy` = 1, but rather `occupancy` of 0 followed by 1 followed by 0.

The table, data and query are in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=679752c268cd6aba070dbc11a79633a3) here (and at the end of this answer), but I'll explain my reasoning.

The first query to run is this one:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT d.room_code,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY room_time) AS rn,
         LAG(d.occupancy) OVER (ORDER BY room_time) AS the_lag,
         d.occupancy, 
         LEAD(d.occupancy) OVER (ORDER BY room_time) AS the_lead,
         LEAD(d.occupancy, 2) OVER (ORDER BY room_time) AS the_2_lead,
         d.room_time, d.day_from_date
  FROM data_point d
)
SELECT * FROM cte1
```

Results look like this (snipped for brevity):

```
room_code   rn  the_lag     occupancy   the_lead    the_2_lead  room_time   day_from_date
EW1A-03-08  1       0   0   1   07/10/2019 08:00:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  2   0   0   1   0   07/10/2019 08:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  3   0   1   0   1   07/10/2019 08:30:00     Wednesday
...
...
```

Note the use of the [offset](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3468/sql-servers-lag-and-lead-functions-to-help-identify-date-differences/) parameter (`LEAD(d.occupancy, 2)`) to the `LEAD()` function. This allows me to check two days ahead - helping to check the existence of runs of `occupancy` = 1.

Then, I ran this query - note the very handy chaining of [CTE](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cte/)s (Common Table Expressions, otherwise known as the WITH clause):

```
cte2 AS
(
  SELECT room_code, 
         rn, 
         the_lag, 
         occupancy, 
         the_lead, 
         the_2_lead, 
         room_time, 
         day_from_date 
  FROM cte1
  WHERE (occupancy = 0 AND the_lead = 1 AND the_2_lead !=1)
)
```

Result:

```
room_code   rn  the_lag     occupancy   the_lead    the_2_lead  room_time   day_from_date
EW1A-03-08  2   0   0   1   0   07/10/2019 08:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  8   1   0   1   0   07/10/2019 10:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  19  0   0   1   0   07/10/2019 15:30:00     Wednesday
```

This gives me the desired slots from the original table with `occupancy` = 0, i.e. rows numbered 2, 8 and 19.

Then, I ran:

```
cte3 AS
(
  SELECT c2.rn AS rn2, c1.rn AS rn1
  FROM cte2 c2
  JOIN cte1 c1 
  ON c2.rn + 1  = c1.rn
)
```

Result:

```
rn2     rn1
  2       3
  8       9
 19      20
```

Which gives me the row numbers of the desired `occupancy` = 0 slots **plus** the row numbers of the desired `occupancy` = 1 slots from the original table.

So, finally, I ran a `UNION` query using both row_number columns from my simple table above:

```
SELECT t1.room_code, t1.rn, t1.occupancy, t1.room_time, t1.day_from_date
FROM cte1 t1 WHERE rn IN (SELECT rn2 FROM cte3)
UNION
SELECT t2.room_code, t2.rn, t2.occupancy, t2.room_time, t2.day_from_date
FROM cte1 t2 WHERE rn IN (SELECT rn1 FROM cte3)
ORDER BY day_from_date
```

Giving the final result:

```
room_code   rn  occupancy   room_time   day_from_date
EW1A-03-08  2   0   07/10/2019 08:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  3   1   07/10/2019 08:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  8   0   07/10/2019 10:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  9   1   07/10/2019 10:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  19  0   07/10/2019 15:30:00     Wednesday
EW1A-03-08  20  1   07/10/2019 15:30:00     Wednesday
6 rows
```

Which looks like the correct answer from the image you posted. If this does not meet your requirements, let me know. I'm afraid that I don't know how efficient it will be on a large dataset. With suitable indexes and once you've pulled out the desired slots of `occupancy` = 0, the amount of records to be pulled out mightn't be too large - YMMV, this will depend on your data.

p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

================= Full SQL, table and data ===========================

Thanks to @HandyD for the original fiddle with [table and data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/253678/34007). As he mentions, in future you should include your tables and data (suitably anonymised) as DDL and DML either in your question or in a fiddle. There are some articles on how to answer questions here on my profile - you might like to take a look? Finally, screenshots are [discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) on StackExchange/StackOverflow.

## SQL:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT d.room_code,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY room_time) AS rn,
         LAG(d.occupancy) OVER (ORDER BY room_time) AS the_lag,
         d.occupancy, 
         LEAD(d.occupancy) OVER (ORDER BY room_time) AS the_lead,
         LEAD(d.occupancy, 2) OVER (ORDER BY room_time) AS the_2_lead,
         d.room_time, d.day_from_date
  FROM data_point d
),
cte2 AS
(
  SELECT room_code, rn, the_lag, occupancy, the_lead, the_2_lead, room_time, day_from_date  FROM cte1
  WHERE (occupancy = 0 AND the_lead = 1 AND the_2_lead !=1)
),
cte3 AS
(
  SELECT c2.rn AS rn2, c1.rn AS rn1
  FROM cte2 c2
  JOIN cte1 c1 
  ON c2.rn + 1  = c1.rn
)
SELECT t1.room_code, t1.rn, t1.occupancy, t1.room_time, t1.day_from_date
FROM cte1 t1 WHERE rn IN (SELECT rn2 FROM cte3)
UNION
SELECT t2.room_code, t2.rn, t2.occupancy, t2.room_time, t2.day_from_date
FROM cte1 t2 WHERE rn IN (SELECT rn1 FROM cte3)
ORDER BY day_from_date
```

## Table:

```
CREATE TABLE data_point
(
  room_code VARCHAR(25),
  occupancy TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK (occupancy IN (0,1)),
  room_time DATETIME,
  day_from_date VARCHAR(15)
);
```

## Data:

```
INSERT INTO data_point (room_code, occupancy, room_time, day_from_date)
VALUES
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 08:00', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 08:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 1, '10/07/2019 08:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 09:00', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 1, '10/07/2019 09:00', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 1, '10/07/2019 09:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 1, '10/07/2019 10:00', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 10:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 1, '10/07/2019 10:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 11:00', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 11:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 12:00', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 12:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 13:00', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 13:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 14:00', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 14:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 15:00', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 15:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 1, '10/07/2019 15:30', 'Wednesday'),
  ('EW1A-03-08', 0, '10/07/2019 16:00', 'Wednesday');
```